# Rounding when converting from double to float in java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a Minimum Bounding Rectangle from double values to float values.  After the conversion, I need the (float) rectangle to be equal to or contain the (double) rectangle (the float rectangle needs to be bigger than or equal to the double rectangle).  To do that I want to be able to specify which way to round the double to convert it to float.  So, when casting the "Top" of the rectangle, I would round up, but when casting the "Bottom" of the rectangle, I would round down.

Is there a class that allows me to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the `float` to the `double` and if it needs to be slightly larger or smaller you can call floatToIntBits and intToFloatBits with an increment or decrement as required.

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.ceil( double ); - round up
Math.round( double ); - round down
```